# Custom iOS Twitter Authentication page?

Tags: objective-c, ios, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am making a mobile application where users can connect their twitter accounts to the app. I am just kinda curious what's the best way to do it.

Right now, I would love to be able to make my own custom page (without having to use a UIWebView).

Is this possible? If how, so?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand, you don't want the user to be redirected to Twitter's OAuth authorization web page. You can use xAuth instead, but you have to send Twitter an email why you want this, and they won't allow xAuth for your app until it is in a very late development state (when your app is almost complete). You can find the manual for xAuth in the [Twitter development documentation](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/xauth).

Basically, what xAuth does is it allows desktop and mobile applications to skip the `request_token` and authorize steps and jump right to the `access_token` step. This way, you can provide the user with custom fields (e.g. `UITextField` objects) to fill their username and password in. Just make sure you don't save them anywhere, only the access token. Good luck. :)

Comment: Emailed them and waiting to get a response! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

A quick web search reveals [MGTwitterEngine](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/02/22/mgtwitterengine-twitter-from-cocoa)

Comment: @phpnerd211 if you read the error messages, you see that you need the OAuthConsumer framework also.