# Can I use STTwitter Library for Twitter login?

Tags: ios, twitter, oauth, vine, sttwitter

I am new in ios app development. I have to create an app with twitter login. Using account.framework it works fine. But I need to create my own view for enter username and password field of twitter user. Can I use STTwitter library for twitter login with custom UI.

NB: The login with twitter is similar to "Vine" app.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156089/custom-ios-twitter-authentication-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use STTwitter to login on Twitter via a custom UI, providing that your consumer tokens are [XAuth enabled](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/oauth/xauth).

If they are not, then you should open the Twitter website as demonstrated in the demo project, see [How to open twitter login page from iOS application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24548534/how-to-open-twitter-login-page-from-ios-application/24548801#24548801).